# How do I upgrade to the newest Firefox via YaST in OpenSuSE 11.x?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, software-installation, upgrade

I'm running OpenSuSE 11.2 and I would like to upgrade to the newest version of Firefox (v 8 I believe at the time of this question).  I'm not interested in extracting a tarball, I would like to do it via RPM.

Going to this website, http://en.opensuse.org/Firefox#Latest_version, it points me to the Firefox repositories here at http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/.  I added both the [SLE 11](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/SLE_11/) and [OpenSuSE](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/SUSE_Factory/) factory repositories via `YaST->Software->Software Repositories`.  When I go to `Software Management` and search for firefox, I do not see version 8 but my current version.

[image]

If I browse the repositories in the browser, however, I plainly see version 8 in both repositories.  Installing by clicking on the rpm doesn't work, however, as it cannot manage dependencies that way.

Comment: OpenSUSE _11.2_ or _12.1_?

Comment: 11.2 is the OS I'm running.

Comment: 11.2 is no longer supported; you must upgrade to at least 11.3 (for which support will end soon).

Comment: To add on to what Marting is trying to say, there might NOT be a way to use `zypper` to accomplish what you're trying to do. To ensure that all the dependencies actually work, you'll need to upgrade your distro to a more recent version.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  That is somewhat of a bummer, as in some of the Debian based distributions, I can simply add a repo that has the latest Firefox version, and I don't have to worry about it.  Oh well, each Linux OS has pros and cons.

Comment: Perhaps you have to raise the priority for the Firefox-repos. I do not know which repository wins if they are all the same priority and provide the same rpm. Raising the priority means to lower the number (afaik). Default is 99, so change it to 98. But beware: the new priority will give ALL rpms in that repository a higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Drill down the repo to http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/openSUSE_12.1/i586/MozillaFirefox-8.0-2.1.i586.rpm, download the RPM and double click it, or run `rpm -i MozillaFirefox-8.0-2.1.i586.rpm` from a terminal (might require sudo)

Comment: That doesn't quite work, because it errors out based on dependencies.  That's why I want to include the whole repo, so those dependencies will be taken care of.  Thanks though.